# Compilation throws `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

Trying to implement a custom JSONB binding that maps to an object containing a map. Generated code throws a `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied` error caused by the following line:

```kotlin
val SOME_FIELD: TableField<SomeRecord, Jsonb?> = createField(DSL.name("meta"), SQLDataType.JSONB.nullable(false).defaultValue(DSL.field("'{}'::jsonb", SQLDataType.JSONB)), this, "", JsonbBinding())
```

Here's my configuration:

```kotlin
class JsonbBinding : Binding<Any, Jsonb> {

    private val mapper = ObjectMapper()

    override fun converter(): Converter<Any, Jsonb> {
        return object : Converter<Any, Jsonb> {
            override fun from(dbObject: Any?): Jsonb {
                if (dbObject == null) return Jsonb()

                val props = mapper.readValue<MutableMap<String, Any>>(dbObject.toString())

                return Jsonb(props)
            }

            override fun to(userObject: Jsonb?): Any? {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(userObject)
            }

            override fun fromType(): Class<Any> {
                return Any::class.java
            }

            override fun toType(): Class<Jsonb> {
                return Jsonb::class.java
            }

        }
    }

    override fun sql(ctx: BindingSQLContext<Jsonb>) {
        ctx.render()?.let {
            if (it.paramType() == ParamType.INLINED) {
                it.visit(
                    DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value())
                ).sql("::jsonb")
            } else {
                it.sql("?::jsonb")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun register(ctx: BindingRegisterContext<Jsonb>) {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR)
    }

    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetStatementContext<Jsonb>) {
        ctx.statement().setString(
            ctx.index(),
            ctx.convert(converter()).value()?.toString()
        )
    }

    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Jsonb>) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetResultSetContext<Jsonb>) {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetStatementContext<Jsonb>) {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetSQLInputContext<Jsonb>) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }
}
```

```xml
<forcedType>
   <userType>org.example.Jsonb</userType>
   <binding>org.example.JsonbBinding</binding>
   <includeExpression>.*</includeExpression>
   <includeTypes>jsonb</includeTypes>
</forcedType>
```

Also, it seems like the line causing problems is mapping database data to JOOQ's default JSONB object. Is that what's causing the issue? Is there anything I may want to do about it? Is there some other way of doing mapping database JSONB data to a map by JOOQ?

Comment: Why do you need the custom `Jsonb` type? Anything you can't do with jOOQ's out of the box type, which already takes care of all you're doing with this binding?

Comment: The mapping that is already there in JOOQ only maps to a string. What I want to achieve is to have the DB representation mapped to a `Map<String, Any>`. My `Jsonb` is an object that wraps a field with that type to avoid problems with generics. @LukasEder

Comment: But in your question, you're not mapping to `Any`. You're mapping to `Jsonb`. When does that other mapping happen in your opinion? Perhaps, instead of asking about what went wrong in this case, you could ask how to achieve what you ultimately want to achieve? I think my answer will be more useful to you, in that case :)

Comment: Oh, I get it. You don't want to map `Any` to `Jsonb`. You want to map `JSONB` to `Any`!

Comment: Wait. I'm confused. :D I want to map DB's `JSONB` to my `Jsonb` (or a map). Have I messed up that bad?

Comment: Well, your code examples definitely don't hint at wanting to map between `JSONB` and `Jsonb`. And I don't think you'll have to, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the type variables on [`Binding<T, U>`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Binding.html) here:

- `T` is the database / JDBC type (in this case [`org.jooq.JSONB`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSONB.html))
- `U` is the user type (in this case `Any`)

You have to implement the binding the other way round: `Binding<JSONB?, Any?>`. Since jOOQ already takes care of properly binding the `JSONB` type to JDBC, you can probably do with your `Converter<JSONB?, Any?>` implementation alone, and attach that to your generated code instead:

```kotlin
class JsonbConverter : Converter<JSONB?, Any?> { ... }
```

Also, you don't have to use your own `Jsonb` type to wrap JSON data here.